# how can I set the width and height of svg text element

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, text

Here I have an svg text element in which I set the text of a div by using

```
text.innerHTML=div.innerText;
```

it sets the text but it shows the whole text only in single line but I have text with enter key in div. I have set the height and width of text element in style and as attribute but it doesn't reflect the effects. The div is

```
<div style="border:1px solid;position:absolute;top:165px;left:276px;height:60px;width:100px;overflow:auto;" id="editableDiv1" contenteditable="true">My text is text</div>
```

The text element is

```
 <svg height="100%" width="100%" id="mySVG">
     <text style="border:1px solid;position:absolute;top:165px;left:276px;height:60px;width:100px;overflow:auto;" x="193" y="134" id="textElement" text-anchor="start" xml:space="preserve" width="100px">
         My text is here
     </text>
 </svg>
```

Comment: For SVG as for html it's the font-size CSS property that sets the height (and width) of text.

Comment: sir I want  my text as enter key pressed, but it will come up only in single line.

Comment: that's how SVG works, no wrapping except what you do manually with tspan elements.

Comment: I saw what you wanted already. SVG doesn't work that way. You could use a foreignObject tag and put an html div in it since a div gives you what you want here.

Comment: @RobertLongson Can we use `foreignObject` safely in all latest browsers? Or it can be problematic?

Comment: Edge supports it, IE doesn't. Most other browsers support it.

Comment: @RobertLongson I have used foreignObject but after that I need conversion of svg into png then it doesn't work.

Comment: Then you'll need to write a solution yourself from scratch, doing the editing and wrapping via javascript. Good luck with that project.

Comment: ok thanks for your suggestion